# localhost redirected you too many times when using header ()

Tags: php

Hi am getting this error when I am trying to send a redirect to the login page.
here is my code...

> The localhost page isn’t working
>
> localhost redirected you too many times. Try clearing your cookies.
>   ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

anything I am trying it's giving me this error.

any suggestions would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
<?php 
if(!$session->is_signed_in()){

    header("Location:login.php");


    } else{
         header("Location:logout.php");

} ?>
```

and this

```
class Session{

    private $signed_in = false;
    public $user_id;

    public function __construct(){
            session_start();
        $this->check_the_login();

    }
// check the value of signed in property - getter method

    public function is_signed_in(){

        return $this->signed_in;
    }

// login method 

    public function login($user){

        if($user){
            $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
            $this->signed_in = true;
        }


    }
// log out method 

    public function logout(){

        unset($this->$_SESSION['user_id']);
        unset($this->user_id);
        $this->signed_in = false;


    }


// check the login method

    private function check_the_login(){

            if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){

                $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
                $this->signed_in = true;

            }else{

                unset($this->user_id);
                $this->signed_in = false;
            }

        }
    }

$session = new Session();
```

Comment: put `exit()` after `header()`

Comment: What page is the first bit of code from? `login.php`?

Comment: I placed exit() after the header and I am getting the same result.
@Jon - first bit of code it's part of the header of index.php

Comment: start session session_start();

Comment: @Cristi In your dev tools, under network, you should see what redirects are happening. What files are being redirecting to?

Comment: @Jon - the page is redirected like about 20 times to login.php - **status code: 302 method Get**

Comment: @Cristi So in login.php, you have something that's redirecting to itself. Have you got the same code in login.php as you say you have in index.php?

Comment: @John - thanks a lot John, that was the issue...in the login.php I had included header.php instead of the initialiser  init.php meaning that exactly like you said I had the same bit of code in both index and login page...changed that and now it's working... easy fix but when you're a newbie like me it's taking two days. Thanks again Jon for your answers and for taking the time to look through my code :)

Answer (score 2):

**Seems that your logout method has error.** Replace this line `unset($this->$_SESSION['user_id']);` to `unset($_SESSION['user_id']);` and try

```
public function logout(){
    unset($this->$_SESSION['user_id']);
    unset($this->user_id);
    $this->signed_in = false;
}
```

Should be like below

```
public function logout(){
    unset($_SESSION['user_id']);
    unset($this->user_id);
    $this->signed_in = false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `POST` request in your form.  I had this problem using a redirect after a `get` request from. Doing two `get` requests, one from the `form`, and one from the `redirect` causes an infinite loop.